# PhpStorm minify multiple JavaScript files in 1

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm

I wanted to minify my JavaScript files using PhpStorm's file watcher but I can't get it working the way I would like it to.

I have installed uglify-js. In the file watcher I tried the following:

> Arguments: `$FileName$ -o $FileDir$.min.js --style compressed`
>   Output paths to refresh: `$FileDir$.min.js`

The problem is that there is just 1 file being minified each time not all in one.

The other problem is that I would like to output a sourcemap but I don't know how to do this nor where to put it (arguments or output paths).

I hope someone could help me with these settings.

Comment: File Watchers were designed primarily to perform some external actions on file on save -- they are called for each modified file. If you process multiple files in one go using File Watcher then you need to hardcode all file names (instead of using current file macro `$FileName$` for that), unless, of course, uglify supports file masks (e.g. `/path/to/folder/*.js`). If you modify 2 files from the target list  then File Watcher will be called for each of them .. so even with hard coded file names it will be performed twice.

Comment: Considering the above I would suggest using some Grunt or Gulp task for that -- it's more suitable for such tasks. P.S. if you wish you could actually use such grunt/gulp task inside File Watcher (by providing right path and parameters there) but better solution would be using grunt's/gulp's `watch` module/functionality.

Comment: @LazyOne oke well I was hoping for a easier solution but I'll give Grunt or Gulp another go

Comment: @LazyOne if you would like to add the 2 comments as 1 answer :P We can close this question becuase I went with Gulp for now and it's doing what I need it to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few notes on File Watchers:

- File watchers were designed primarily to perform some external actions on file on save.
- File watcher gets called for each modified file.
- If you want to process multiple files in one go (for example: merge 2+ files into 1) using File Watcher then you need to hard code all participating files (as opposed to using current file macro `$FileName$` for that), unless, of course, uglify supports file masks (e.g. `/path/to/folder/*.js`).
- If you modify 2 files from the target list then File Watcher will be called for each of them so even with hard coded file names it will be performed twice (same job done twice).

Considering the above **I suggest using Grunt or Gulp task for that instead** -- they're more suitable for such requirements.

**P.S.** 
If you wish you could actually use such grunt/gulp task inside File Watcher (same as calling it in terminal/console manually) but because of point #3 above the better solution would be using Grunt's/Gulp's `watch` module/functionality if you need automatic execution of task.