# Minify all js files with closure in folder in WebStorm

Tags: javascript, node.js, webstorm, minify, google-closure-compiler

I am using WebStorm File Watcher with Google closure compiler to minify my JavaScript files. I am using node.js v4.6.

The problem with WebStorm's file watcher is that I have to manually make some change to a JavaScript file in order to trigger a minify operation. This is too tedious if I have many JavaScript files. I will have to do this one by one.

How can I run a single operation to minify all the files located in a particular folder?

Comment: There is a similar answer, http://stackoverflow.com/a/35710331/5788489

Comment: You can force re-run file watcher manually without modifying any files as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20012655/783119

Answer (score 1):

This is how you run a single operation to minify all files located in your working folder on Webstorm.

- On the Project panel, click and select the folder at the top.
- Press (Ctrl + Shift + A) to activate dialog box for action.
- Search for "run file w". Choose "Run File Watchers" entry when it appears.